# Integral $x^{-x}\,dx$ using Taylor's?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

So I'm good w my comparison tests but is this an elliptical function?
$$ \int_0^int_12 x^{-x} \, dx$$

Does one use Taylor's integration in this?

Comment: Which comparisons have you tried?

Comment: so I was thinking 1/x^2 which is larger than 1/x , making it defined at 0, therefore it converges ?

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\epsilon \frac{dx}{x^2}$ *diverges* for all $\epsilon > 0$, so we can't compare the two integrals outright. But for $2 \leq x$, $\frac{1}{x^x} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$, so $\int_2^\infty x^{-x} \,dx$ converges, and thus the given integral converges or diverges iff $\int_0^2 x^{-x} \,dx$ does, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x^{-x} < e^{-x}$ when $x> e,$ so the integral  from $e$ to $+\infty$ is no problem.

On the interval $(0,e]$ the function is continuous, so it will be enough to prove that $x^{-x}$ approaches some finite number as $x\downarrow0.$

$$
\log_e (x^{-x}) = -x \log_e x = \frac{-\log_e x}{ 1/x}.
$$
The numerator and denominator both approach $+\infty$ as $x\downarrow 0,$ so we can attempt to use L'Hospital's rule. And that quickly shows that the limit of that logarithm is $0;$ therefore $\lim\limits_{x \, \downarrow \, 0} x^{-x} = 1.$

Thus the integral converges.

Comment: You don't need L'Hospital's rule for that: it's a basic high-school result that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x=0$.

Comment: Just using the definition of the function: $x^{-x}=\mathrm e^{-x\ln x}$, and the continuity of the exponential.

Comment: @Bernard : Just after posting my question I realized that there's a simple way to prove the result without L'Hopital's rule. But I don't think your argument works. The exponential function is continuous, but that works only if $x\ln x$ approaches some limit as $x$ approaches $0,$ which is the very thing to be proved.

Comment: Everyone in high school is supposed to know that!

Comment: @Bernard : What is your proposed "basic-high-school" way of proving this result? Your argument about continuity of the exponential doesn't do it for the reason I mentioned.  If I wanted to prove it to high-school students who don't know L'Hopital's rule, I would do this:
$$ x\ln x = \frac {-u} {e^u} \quad \text{where } {-u} = \ln x \text{ so that } e^u = \frac 1 x  $$ and then observe that every time $u$ increases by $1,$ the denominator far more than doubles while the numerator is multiplied by barely more than $1,$ so the fraction approaches $0. \qquad$

Comment: In high school, one learns that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\tfrac{\ln x}x=0$ and, as an immediate corollary, that $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x=0$, which is, as you point it, required to use the continuity of the exponential function.

Comment: My way of proving $\lim\limits_{x\,\to\,\infty} \dfrac{\ln x} x = 0$ would be essentially what I said in a comment above, i.e. transform it to $\dfrac u {e^u}.$ (Unless I used L'Hopital's rule instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Divide the integral into two pieces $[0,2]$ and $[2,\infty]$.  For the first part show that the integrand is finite, so $\int_0^2$ is finite.  For the second part $x^{-x}\lt x^{-2}$ and $\int_2^\infty x^{-2} \, dx$ is finite.